# Searchable Plugin error

Tags: grails, searchable

In the Grails 2.5.1 project i'm using [Searchable Plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/searchable) but i got the below error ,

```
context.GrailsContextLoaderListener , Error initializing the application: org/hibernate/impl/SessionFactoryImpl
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/impl/SessionFactoryImpl
```

,  after searching i found that the plugin is not compatible with hibernate 4 , is there any way to make it work rather downgrading the hibernate or is there any good plugin easy to use as this one and for sure must support hibernate 4 .

Comment: how about you take a look at [this one](https://grails.org/plugin/elasticsearch). Yours was last updated 2 years ago. ElasticSearch plugin - a week ago! :)

Comment: I would also suggest using ElasticSearch, but what version of Searchable are you using?

Comment: @JacobPersi version 0.6.9 , is there any examples and tutorials for Elastic search

Comment: Here is a fairly recent guide: http://sufyanshoaib.com/grails/elasticsearch/2015/01/29/grails-elasticsearch.html